# Create a scatterplot from the data of two dataframes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two dataframes in python. The content of them is the following:

Table=conn

```
A   B   relevance
1   3   0.7
2   7   0.1
5   20  2
6   2   7
```

table=point

```
Point  Lat   Lon
1      45.3  -65.2
2      34.4  -60.2
3      40.2  -60.1
20     40.4  -63.1
```

In the first table, column A represents an origin, column B a destination and the relevance of the link.

On the other hand, in the second table we have for each point (origin or destination) its coordinates.

The problem is that I want to create a visualization in Python that allows to query the coordinates of each origin or destination (column A and B of the first table) in the second table and make a scatterplot with it. Then, link each of the origins and destinations of the first column taking into account the relevance with thicker lines as it has more relevance.

link refers to the line that joins the points in the graphic representation.

Any idea? I've started with a very basic code approach but I'm really having trouble following along.

```
for row in conn.interrows():
    row[1][0]
    row[1][1]
    row[1][3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have two DataFrames: `point` and `conn`, right?

```
# To set indexes of "point" equal to "Points"
point.set_index(point.Point, inplace=True)

# config width of lines
min_width = 0.5
max_width = 4.0

min_relevance = conn.relevance.min()
max_relevance = conn.relevance.max()
slope = (max_width - min_width)/(max_relevance - min_relevance)
widths = min_width + slope*(conn.relevance - min_relevance)

# plot lines
for i in range(len(conn)):
    origin = conn.loc[i, 'A']
    destin = conn.loc[i, 'B']
    lat = point.loc[[origin, destin], 'Lat']
    lon = point.loc[[origin, destin], 'Lon']
    plt.plot(lat, lon, c='red', lw=widths[i])

# plot points
plt.plot(point.Lat, point.Lon, ls='', marker='o', c='blue')
```

Comment: Hi @Joao_PS your code worked perfeclty. On the other hand, I would like to add a small functionality: imagine that the point table has a variable that is num people, how can I represent by the thickness of the point the number of people?

Comment: This is the marker size. Define a `min_mk_size` and `max_mk_size`.  Config the markers size simillary I did to `widths` (but using the num people). You must to get a array or dataframe... maybe called `mk_sizes`. So, pass the `markersize=mk_sizes` option in `plt.plot`.